# C++ : How to create a copy constructor of array that has a pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, list, templates, copy-constructor

I have

```
template <class T>
class arrList: public linearList<T> {
public: 
      arrList() {}
      arrList(const arrList<T>& List);
      ~arrList() {delete[] element; }
protected:
      void indexCheck(int indx) const;
      T* element;
      int arrLength;
      int listSize;
};
```

And the copy constructor is

```
template<class T>
inline arrList<T>::arrList(const arrList<T>& List) {
       element = List.element;
       arrLength = List.arrLength;
       listSize = List.listSize;
}
```

But im not sure if this is correct for T* element, and also if I have to insert the void function in the copy constructor too.
I am new to this, and I don't know a lot about it, so any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: What you have implemented is identical to `arrList(const arrList<T>& List) = default;`.

Comment: this should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy)

Comment: The copy constructor you designed creates multiple objects that will each try to `delete` the same `element` pointer upon destruction.  This will not go well.

Comment: Where is the copy for the `linearList<T>` part of the class? And you should probably have a move constructor instead of copy constructor. For a copy constructor like you have you need `std::shared_ptr<T> element;`.